# using collection and if else statement in java in optimize way

Tags: java, if-statement, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a below code which is working as expected and I want to optimize it, possibly if using  methods of stream.

```
List<List<String>> colorsList = List.of(
   List.of("red","maroon"),
   List.of("blue, skyblue"),
   List.of("pink"));

int var1 = 5;
List<String> listReturn = new ArrayList<>();

for(List<String> innerList: colorsList){
    if(var1 == 5){
        if(innerList.contains("blue")){
            listReturn.addAll(innerList);
        }
    }else if(var1 == 10){
        if(innerList.contains("pink") || innerList.contains("red")){
            listReturn.addAll(innerList);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I am returning a single List listReturn combining 1 or more List from original colorsList based on conditions.
Is there a better and optimized way to write above?

Comment: Sure you can do that but it will just destroy the readability of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could factor out the predicate, this way you don't have to repeat the code of going over and filtering the list:

```
List<List<String>> colorsList = List.of(
        List.of("red","maroon"),
        List.of("blue, skyblue"),
        List.of("pink"));

int var1 = 5;

// switch expression
Predicate<List<String>> predicate = switch (var1) {
    case 5 -> innerList -> innerList.contains("blue");
    case 10 -> innerList -> innerList.contains("pink") || innerList.contains("red");
    default -> innerList -> true; // if something else than 5 or 10 accept all
};

List<String> listReturn = colorsList.stream()
               .filter(predicate).flatMap(List::stream).toList();
```

Comment: The original code doesn’t accept all when `var1` is neither `5` nor `10`, but none. So it’s preferable not to iterate over the original list in this case, when the result predictably will be an empty list.

Comment: This seems better way but I am using Java 11 and its not allowing to use switch expression in predicate

Comment: @usr_11 Switch expressions are a new feature of Java 14, so you can't use them in Java 11. You might want to see if you can upgrade to Java 17 (the current long-term support version of Java).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following code, you should also check colorsList is null or not

```java
List<List<String>> colorsList = List.of(
        List.of("red","maroon"),
        List.of("blue", "skyblue"),
        List.of("pink"));

int var1 = 5;
List<String> listReturn = new ArrayList<>();

if (5 == var1) {
    colorsList.stream()
            .filter(innerList -> innerList.contains("blue"))
            .forEach(listReturn::addAll);
} else if (10 == var1) {
    colorsList.stream()
            .filter(innerList -> innerList.contains("pink") || innerList.contains("red"))
            .forEach(listReturn::addAll);
}
```

Comment: I don’t think that there is a reason to suggest an additional `null`-check here, but the suggestion to move the `5 == var1`/`10 == var1` check out of the iteration is pointing into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to write this code, I will first create a stream of colorsList and then filter it. If the filter condition is true, the item will be added to the output.
Next, we use flatMap() to flatten the nested lists into a single stream of strings.

```
List<String> listReturn = colorsList.stream()
        .filter(innerList -> var1 == 5 && innerList.contains("blue")
                || var1 == 10 && (innerList.contains("pink") || innerList.contains("red")))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```